# Get stack trace for all execution frames in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace

I know how to get a stack trace for the currently executing "thread" (`console.trace` or `new Error().stack`), but how can I get a stack trace for all the different "threads" in a running Node.js process?  Basically I want something like `thread apply all bt` in GDB.

Note: I am aware that Node is single-threaded and doesn't really have multiple threads.  But there are still multiple "logical threads" that can coexist at the same time - for instance if a webserver is has multiple requests that are in the process of being served, but several of them were descheduled in an `async` function call or are blocked waiting on i/o.

Comment: I just found this post (https://www.reaktor.com/blog/debugging-node-js-applications-using-core-dumps/) which looks like basically what I want, but it only runs on Solaris.  Is there a more native solution for doing the same thing that will work on my Linux or OSX machine without me needing to set up a Solaris VM?

Comment: There aren't stack traces hanging around for things that are using asynchronoous I/O.  Those things `return` back to the event loop, clearing the stack frame entirely. A callback then gets called sometime in the future, starting a new stack frame.  There are function contexts/closures that survive and will be available to the callbacks (if they are inline), but those are not stack frames.  So, there is no list of multiple stack frames at once.

Comment: But even if functions blocked on I/O return back to the event loop, since they can be rescheduled when the i/o comes in, the callback that is stored in the event loop must have information about the call stacks of the functions that are blocked and waiting.  Is there really no way to iterate over the callbacks registered in the event loop that are waiting for i/o (or a promise to resolve, or on a mutex) and print the stacks of all of them?  How are you supposed to debug deadlocks in Node.js?

Comment: @stbrody You mean callbacks that resolve a promise that resumes an `async` function? I don't think those suspended function calls are registered directly on the event loop.

Comment: @stbrody - You don't seem to understand how it works.  When a function is waiting on I/O, it returned.  It has no call stack any more.  It's callback, internal to the function, will get called sometime in the future, but the original call stack is gone.  That function ran and returned.  Even if you're using `await`, the function still returned a promise at the point of the first `await`.  There is no call stack.  There is a function context and lexical scope which is a very different thing than a call stack.  Those are garbage collected based on internal references and aren't like call stacks.

Comment: I expanded on my comments in an answer below to explain why there is still only one Javascript call stack in nodejs, even when using asynchronous I/O, even when using `async` and `await`.